# How to initialize 1000 of strings programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I want to initialize 1000 of strings in ma app list wise

```
public static final String[] IMAGES = {"1","2","3","4","5","6",......"1000"};
```

Comment: Will the strings be a variety of different things? Or just as you stated, the numbers 1 - 1000 as strings?

Comment: Matt Clark Your code is not working.i have already tried like this."syntex error :,after delete this token"

Comment: Why allocate a 1000 strings if you can infer the correct textual value for a specific index at runtime? I mean, the return value for `String.valueOf(index-1)` will be indentical to `IMAGES[index]`, but the former means you don't have to keep a 1000 strings in memory.

Comment: @MH what are u saying ..how to do that in runtime?

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan: I'm saying it makes little sense to allocate a `String[1000]` with just a sequence of `[1...n]` numbers. In stead of retrieving i.e. `IMAGES[n]` for `n=5` (which will be `6`), why not just do `String.valueOf(n+1)`. The latter will be `6` too, but you didn't have to allocate 1000 strings in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
public static final String[] IMAGES;
static {
    IMAGES = new String[1000];
    for (int i = 1; i <= IMAGES.length; ++i) {
        IMAGES[i - 1] = String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This starts adding strings at index 1 and produces an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because of `<=`.

Comment: @Jrop - Oops. Fixed. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan - you might want to specify what syntax error. His code compiles just fine.

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan - What syntax error? My version of Eclipse is happy with it.

Comment: @Ted Hopp  ur code is works like a charam .@matt clark answers is not working

Answer (score 1):

If the string itself is just going to be the integer representing its position in the array, create the array and run a `for` loop.

```
String[] IMAGES = new String[1000];

for(int x = 0; x < IMAGES.length; x++){
    IMAGES[x] = Integer.toString(x);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a problem in it that caused it to go out of bounds. Here it is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like :

```
public static final String[] IMAGES;
static {
    IMAGES = new String[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES.length; i++) {
        IMAGES[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bastien Thanx ..but Ted Hopp gave the answer first.

Comment: The solution proposed by @TedHopp is a bit more optimized without the (i+1) (even though the loop is done only once). Go with his solution.

Comment: @Bastein could u tell me y the second answer is not working.i have tried something like that before posting this....

Comment: @Divya because you need to put the "for" inside a method

Comment: @TedHopp at the end it is exactly the same (besides the indexing) :)

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan no problem, this is what Stackoverflow is for, help each other.